# Seemingly immutable dict in object instance

Tags: python, object, dictionary, immutability, cartopy

If I run the following `cartopy` code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
globe = ccrs.LambertCylindrical()
print(globe.proj4_params)
globe.proj4_params['a'] = 5
print(globe.proj4_params)
```

I get:

```
{'proj': 'cea', 'lon_0': 0.0, 'a': 57.29577951308232, 'ellps': 'WGS84'}
{'proj': 'cea', 'lon_0': 0.0, 'a': 57.29577951308232, 'ellps': 'WGS84'}
```

Impying that the `proj4_params` property is immutable.

But it's just a bog standard `dict`:

```
print(type(globe.proj4_params))

<class 'dict'>
```

Which, since it's implemented in C, can't be overwritten to have this kind of behavior (at least not safely).

Ok, but the code for this class is [dead simple](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/_modules/cartopy/crs.html#LambertCylindrical), so there's something wrong with my understanding. Can someone explain to me why I am getting this behavior?

**Edit**:

The following:

```
projection.proj4_params = dict(projection.proj4_params)
```

Results in:

```
*** AttributeError: attribute 'proj4_params' of 'cartopy._crs.CRS' objects is not writable
```

Comment: I suspect `globe.proj4_params` is a property that gives you a new copy of the dict each time you access it, precisely to prevent you from doing this.

Comment: Note that the class isn't simple at all -- LambertCylindrical doesn't set the proj4_params property, its init calls the init in its superclass (_RectangularProject) which calls the init in its superclass (Projection) -- which doesn't have an init at all, but it does have metaclasses. Actually I have no idea where the proj4_params property comes from.

Comment: What happens if you do `params = globe.proj4_params; params['a'] = 5; print(params)`?

Comment: This behaves as expected, returning `{'ellps': 'WGS84', 'a': 5, 'proj': 'cea', 'lon_0': 0.0}`. It does not, however, mutate `globe.proj4_params`.

Comment: Yeah, so the dictionary you get is perfectly normal and mutable, but accessing the property globe.proj4_params gets you a new copy each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ensure your params are a dictionary by converting it to one first.

```
params = dict(globe.proj4_params)
```

Then if you print

```
print type(params)

<type 'dict'>
```

Notice the `<type 'dict'>` instead of the `<class 'dict'>` in your question. The dict you're using may be a custom class that's immutable but uses the same `dict` name.

Comment: I need to modify the original parameter in-place, though, not create a copy of it. This did hint at the problem though, I've edited the question.

Comment: Based on the updates to your question, it looks like that isn't possible. Why do you need to edit the values in place?

Comment: If it's not possible, I would still like to know *why* it's not possible. I get that you can set write permissions in C classes, but wouldn't that cause `type` to report some other object type, e.g. `<type 'immutabledict'>`?

Comment: As for the application, I'm writing a function that takes `ccrs` objects as inputs and modifies them in-place to insert some sensible defaults when they're not present. Since it doesn't seem to be possible to do this way I may have to roll my own wrappers, because there's [a lot of options](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/crs/projections.html)...

Comment: @ResMar it's reporting `<class 'dict'>` instead of `<type 'dict'>` so it might be a custom class that's designed to be immutable by default.

Comment: Wow, that's subtle. I don't know enough Cython to verify, but I think you're right, so I'll mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `proj4_params` object is finally defined in `Projection`'s superclass `CRS`, which is supplied by the private, cython module `_crs.pyx` within cartopy. When a cartopy CRS' proj4_params is defined, it's just defined as a variable within the class rather than as a class variable (that is, it **isn't** defined as `self.proj4_params`). This is a fair part of the reason why you can't modify the values of the proj4 params.

For what it's worth, I believe this is the correct way for cartopy CRS' to behave. The `proj4_params` element of each CRS is a direct reference to a canonical definition of the underlying projection that cartopy is providing within Python. These canonical definitions are maintained by the proj.4 organisation (for example, [Lambert Cylindrical is here](http://proj4.org/projections/cea.html)), so modifying the `proj4_params` would mean your projection is *no longer a Lambert Cylindrical projection*.

If you particularly need a cartopy CRS that's *almost* a Lambert Cylindrical, you could always create your own crs by duplicating the code in cartopy's own `LambertCylindrical` class. So long as you maintain the inheritance in your own class you should be able to use it as you would one of cartopy's built-in CRS'. Note if you do modify the `proj4_params` for your own class it might not work because your specified params do not match to anything in proj.4 itself. In this case you could look into modifying your CRS' [globe](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/crs/index.html#cartopy.crs.Globe) attribute to make the projection changes you need.